# Как вывести Клавиатуру когда есть фокус?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Как вывести Клавиатуру когда есть фокус в `EditText`?

К примеру запускаю `Dialog`. Там есть `EditText`. Когда `dialog` запускается то видно что фокус принимает `EditText` но клавиатура не появляется. Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда получили ссылку на поле ввода, вызываете метод `post()` он запустит выполнение метода `Keyboard.show()` после того как вьюха успешно заатачится на экран

```
editText.post(() -> Keyboard.show(editText))
```

Ну и сам метод показывания клавиатуры. Вынесите в утилитный класс `Keyboard`, чтобы можно было использовать по всему проекту

```
public class Keyboard {

    public static void show(@NonNull View view) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
}
```